# Using Foundation 5 with Hammer for Mac

Tags: zurb-foundation, hammer

I'm starting using [Foundation 5](http://foundation.zurb.com/) for a current project and using the command line + Compass to watch for changes to my stylesheet and output CSS, but it takes almost two entire seconds for it to save out my CSS.

I've also been using Hammer (http://hammerformac.com/) a lot this year for optimising my code and was wondering if anyone had used Foundation with Hammer, and was interested on how well they work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand right, the main goal is to accelerate compiling your sass files.
Maybe libsass is what you need. It is C library for compiling sass files

More information you can find here:
http://benfrain.com/lightning-fast-sass-compiling-with-libsass-node-sass-and-grunt-sass/

Comment: Accelerating my Sass compiling is what I'm looking for, but I really do miss being able to use Hammer's includes and clever paths. Do you know if Hammer would work with Foundation? In regards to Libsass, would that mean I no longer can use Compass?

Comment: Foundation is simply a set of styles and mixins. Hammer can compile sass files, thats why works well with Foundation. But the main trouble with Hammer is this: http://hammerformac.com/news/compass.html

Comment: Hmm, damn. I'm just missing Hammer's clever paths, includes and reload function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Hammer documentation has been updated. Check out [Tips & Tricks](http://hammerformac.com/docs/tips) where you'll see this:

> **ZURB Foundation and Hammer**
>   If you're working with ZURB's Foundation framework, you'll need to grab the Standalone Foundation files from GitHub.
>   Simply include the Foundation files in your project, include them in your SCSS files with `@include "foundation/foundation"` and you're good to go!